# How do you represent a x-bit key in code?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, bit

I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the term x-bit key. I'm coding a cipher (TEA, OFB Mode)  of x-bit input. But how do I represent it in code. What sort of variable do I use to contain those digits.

Eg 4-bit key. I understand it means 16 different possibilities etc . So does this mean I literally accept an int of 4 numbers with only 1s and 0s? I'm aware of byte variables as well. But how does that come into play. Can some kind soul please shed some light

Answer (score 0):

Keys are generally multiples of 8 because computers use an 8-bit byte or octet as smallest amount of addressable information. So an 128 bit key for a modern symmetric cipher consists of 128 / 8 = 16 bytes of data. So keys in software are often delivered as a byte array, where each byte can have every of the 256 possible values.

At a lower level the ciphers are usually programmed using 32 or 64 bit words. So sometimes the key has to be delivered as words of that size instead. Commonly a higher level interface is used that converts bytes to the internally used words, so you won't see the representation in words of the key on the outside of the interface.

Object oriented implementations often require an object wrapper around the bytes. Similarly, you can have a key and cipher operations within hardware. In that case a key reference may be used, often represented by an object or C data structure containing the reference. In that case the hardware deals with the bytes and / or words. The Java `SecretKey` interface may represent either a hardware key or a software key (which may be created by using `SecretKeySpec`, which takes a byte array as argument).

A four bit key doesn't represent any viable security level. You could represent it using any 4 bits of a byte, usually the least significant 4 bits. Or you could use the lower 4 bits of an integer. But as indicated, 4 bits doesn't make any sense, and most keys are a multiple of 8 or even 32 bits to make things easier.

---

Asymmetric keys - such as RSA or Elliptic Curve based key - are completely different beasts. These cryptosystems are based on integer arithmetic instead of bit operations. The key size is determined by one of the values in the cryptosystem. For instance for RSA keys the size of the modulus size is used. Because these keys commonly consist of multiple values they need to be encoded in a (preferably standardized) data structure. That data structure is of course commonly bigger than the key size, as the value that defines the key is often part of it.